# ORACLE 9i PLSQL Optimizer causing some performance issues with constant VARIABLES

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, plsql, oracle9i

I'm developing some nightly based batch jobs in which I'm using rowids to locate the record in the table but have always a fallback to some logical key or something if the rowid is not passed.

I developed a little test case to show you what my problem has been and to provide something you can replicate on your own environment.

Create the table and put some data inside

```
create table table_with_4M_records (varchar_column varchar2(7));

begin
  for i in 1..4000000
  loop
    insert into table_with_4M_records(varchar_column) values (''||lpad(i,7,0));
  end loop;
end;
```

And what I found is that if I run something like:

```
DECLARE
  w_rowid constant VARCHAR2(30) := 'AAF6CCAAnAAAaz9AHX';
  w_counter NUMBER;
  w_t0 TIMESTAMP;
  w_t1 TIMESTAMP;
  w_time_diff_in_ms NUMBER:=null;
BEGIN
  w_t0 := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  SELECT count(*) 
  INTO w_counter 
  FROM table_with_4M_records 
  WHERE ((w_rowid IS NOT NULL AND ROWID = w_rowid )
          OR
          (w_rowid IS NULL  /*Then do some heavy operations which I only want to do if the rowid comes with no value*/ )
        );
  w_t1 := SYSTIMESTAMP;      
  SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM diff )*24*60*60*1000 +             --Days
         EXTRACT(HOUR FROM diff )*60*60*1000 +               --Hours
         EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM diff )*60*1000 +                --Minutes
   round(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM diff )*1000)total_milliseconds  --Seconds
    INTO w_time_diff_in_ms
  FROM (SELECT (w_t1-w_t0) diff FROM dual);

  dbms_output.put_line('REC COUNTER: '||w_counter);
  dbms_output.put_line('APROX EXEC TIME IN MILLISECS: '||w_time_diff_in_ms);

END;
```

I get a fetch time of several seconds, something like 5 seconds... weird right? Because I'm using ROWID, should be a direct fetch.

But if I replace the w_rowid in the code with the value. Like so:

```
DECLARE
  w_rowid constant VARCHAR2(30) := 'AAAGg5AAWAAAaffAA0';
  w_counter NUMBER;
  w_t0 TIMESTAMP;
  w_t1 TIMESTAMP;
  w_time_diff_in_ms NUMBER:=null;
BEGIN
  w_t0 := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  SELECT count(*) 
  INTO w_counter 
  FROM table_with_4M_records 
  WHERE (('AAF6CCAAnAAAaz9AHX' IS NOT NULL AND ROWID = 'AAF6CCAAnAAAaz9AHX' )
          OR
          ('AAF6CCAAnAAAaz9AHX' IS NULL  /*Then do some heavy operations witch I only want to do if the rowid comes with no value*/ )
        );
  w_t1 := SYSTIMESTAMP;      
  SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM diff )*24*60*60*1000 +             --Days
         EXTRACT(HOUR FROM diff )*60*60*1000 +               --Hours
         EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM diff )*60*1000 +                --Minutes
   round(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM diff )*1000)total_milliseconds  --Seconds
    INTO w_time_diff_in_ms
  FROM (SELECT (w_t1-w_t0) diff FROM dual);

  dbms_output.put_line('REC COUNTER: '||w_counter);
  dbms_output.put_line('APROX EXEC TIME IN MILLISECS: '||w_time_diff_in_ms);

END;
```

I get an execution time of almost zero. (???)

I found out that the problem is mainly the check if null and if I remove/comment that code I get times near to zero as well...

The last snippet of code is here:

```
DECLARE
  w_rowid constant VARCHAR2(30) := 'AAF6CCAAnAAAaz9AHX';
  w_counter NUMBER;
  w_t0 TIMESTAMP;
  w_t1 TIMESTAMP;
  w_time_diff_in_ms NUMBER:=null;
BEGIN
  w_t0 := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  SELECT count(*) 
  INTO w_counter 
  FROM table_with_4M_records 
  WHERE ((w_rowid IS NOT NULL AND ROWID = w_rowid )
          --OR
          --(w_rowid IS NULL  /*Then do some heavy operations witch I only want to do if the rowid comes with no value*/ )
        );
  w_t1 := SYSTIMESTAMP;      
  SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM diff )*24*60*60*1000 +             --Days
         EXTRACT(HOUR FROM diff )*60*60*1000 +               --Hours
         EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM diff )*60*1000 +                --Minutes
   round(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM diff )*1000)total_milliseconds  --Seconds
    INTO w_time_diff_in_ms
  FROM (SELECT (w_t1-w_t0) diff FROM dual);

  dbms_output.put_line('REC COUNTER: '||w_counter);
  dbms_output.put_line('APROX EXEC TIME IN MILLISECS: '||w_time_diff_in_ms);

END;
```

If any of you have any good tip to overcome this problem I would really appreciate.
If any of you could test this code on your local environment with different versions of oracle I would appreciate as well.

I'm currently running Oracle 9.2I and I thought that the optimizer would be smarter and realize that I'm using a constant varchar2 that isn't changed inside the query. 
If it is not null the first time it will be not null in all test cases on that query... I was clearly wrong

Thank you very much.

Comment: ROWIDs are not guaranteed to be constant outside of a transaction. The database is free to move rows around as it chooses, which thus would change the ROWID. A ROWID is not a substitute for a primary key. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case:

```
WHERE ((w_rowid IS NOT NULL AND ROWID = w_rowid ) OR
          (w_rowid IS NULL  /*Then do some heavy operations*/ )
        );
```

the query optimizer doesn't do a 'lazy' evaluation of the `OR` condition.  It evaluates everything including your 'heavy operations'.  It's not smart enough to recognize that you declared `w_rowid` as constant.

In the second case:

```
WHERE (('AAF6CCAAnAAAaz9AHX' IS NOT NULL AND ROWID = 'AAF6CCAAnAAAaz9AHX' ) OR
          ('AAF6CCAAnAAAaz9AHX' IS NULL  /*Then do some heavy operations*/ )
        );
```

the optimizer can simplify the expression at compile-time because of the constant value, so it ignores the second half of the `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even need to include w_rowid in the SQL code?  You know ahead of time if it is null or not, so hoist it out to the PL/SQL code and optimize your SQL queries for the two different cases (remove some code for clarity):

```
DECLARE
  w_rowid constant VARCHAR2(30) := 'AAF6CCAAnAAAaz9AHX';
  w_counter NUMBER;

BEGIN
  IF w_rowid IS NOT NULL THEN
      SELECT count(*) 
      INTO w_counter 
      FROM table_with_4M_records 
      WHERE ROWID = w_rowid;
  ELSE
      /* do another select if w_rowid is null */
  END IF;


END;
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying but the qhery that gave birth to this problem is a big query with 4 joins and some 50 columns to analize.